# Yum update error - Requires: python26-ordereddict

Tags: yum, rpm, dependencies

Today I tried to update our Amazon Linux servers and got the following error message:

```
$ sudo yum update
---> Package python26-ordereddict.noarch 0:1.1-2.5.amzn1 will be obsoleted
--> Processing Dependency: python26-ordereddict = 1.1 for package: python26-bcdoc-0.16.0-1.9.amzn1.noarch
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: python26-bcdoc-0.16.0-1.9.amzn1.noarch (@amzn-updates)
           Requires: python26-ordereddict = 1.1
           Removing: python26-ordereddict-1.1-2.5.amzn1.noarch (@amzn-main)
               python26-ordereddict = 1.1-2.5.amzn1
           Obsoleted By: python26-2.6.9-2.83.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-updates)
               python26-ordereddict = 1.2
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

This is a Apache PHP webserver, and we don't use Python for web development,  but Linux needs it apparently, and maybe some package that Apache uses needs this - no idea! This error appeared on several servers.

**Questions**

- Is it safe to use `sudo yum update --skip-broken`, or can that break things?
- What does `rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest` do and what is the risk?
- How can I resolve this apparent dependency problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command is safe. It skips all packages with broken dependencies:

```
sudo yum update --skip-broken
```

You can verify all packages skiping checksum validation, yes it is safe:

```
rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Suppose, you can't resolve this, after few days the dependencies will appear in repo. Also you can make bugreport to yours distro vendor.

Answer (score 0):

I had to find the same package as a dependency for salt-minion.  Its on EPEL, so you probably want to do something like this, to set up the new repository.

```
yum install epel-release-5-4
yum install python26-ordereddict
```

Versions will change over time - make sure you get what you need.